# Return Row Numbers with Result

Tags: mongodb, laravel

i am using mongodb database.

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('set @row:=0'));
return \DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('users')->selectRaw('*, @row:=@row+1 as row')->get();
```

show error

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>   Call to a member function prepare() on null

Comment: You are trying to run a SQL statement on MongoDB. That does not work. Please read the documentation - [MongoDB CRUD Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/)

Comment: Just pointing you at the duplicate of what you are attempting to actually do. You cannot get "row numbers" in a MongoDB result. The only "stupid" thing is forcing the whole collection into a single document and then getting the array index. This does not work in practicality because there is a 16MB limit on how much data a single document can have.